# Eclipse hanging in svn+ssh project

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, ssh

Hey! I am running eclipse php helios on windows 7 64bit.

I have created a projected with existing sources, sources from a svn+ssh repository.
I have the project in another pc, which is running ubuntu server 10.10.

My problem is that I can't do a refresh of the project. It hangs when the bar is at half.
I can see the file in php explorer but not with the svn info (the rev is 0)

I have changed in the svn interface to SVNKit.

Do I have to do something else?? What do I need to do to make this work??

Edit: I just left the eclipse updating overnight and it finished updating. It seems there is something that causes the update to take a really long time

Answer (score 1):

Do you have binaries in your repository?

I usually get this problem when trying to checkout a large binary file. It happens with svn://, http:// and svn+ssh://. Usually, I just let it hang in there for a while and it ends up working. It can take few hours though, depending on the size of the file.

Comment: There are a few images in the repository, but those are under 1kb. The rest is just php files.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can muck up SVN on windows is bad file names.  If you have a file that does not meet Windows naming conventions it can hang your SVN checkout.